# How to transform an array of file paths into a hierarchical JSON structure

Tags: c#, json, directory

I am trying to create a JSON of a machine's directory structure given an array of all its files and paths.

The array looks something like this:

```
string[] dirArray = {
"./proc/15/task/15/exe",
"./proc/15/task/15/mounts/mounts.xml",
"./proc/15/task/15/mountinfo/mountinfo.xml",
"./proc/15/task/15/clear_refs/clear_ref.xml",
"./proc/14/loginuid/loginuid.xml",
"./proc/14/sessionid/sessionid.xml",
"./proc/14/coredump_filter/coredump_filter.xml",
"./proc/14/io/io.xml"
}
```

The target JSON I am aiming for is something like this:

```
{
   ".":
   {
        "file":
        {
            "name":"fileInRoot.xml"
        },
        "proc":
        {
            "file":
            {
                "name":"fileInProc.xml"
            },
            "15":
            {
                "file":
                {
                    "name":"fileIn15.xml"
                },
                "task":
                {
                    "file":
                    {
                        "name":"fileInTask.xml"
                    },
                    "15":
                    {
                        "file":
                        {
                            "name":"fileInTask.xml"
                        },
                        "mounts":
                        {
                            "file":
                            {
                                "name":"fileInMounts.xml"
                            }
                        },
                        "mountsInfo":
                        {
                            "file":
                            {
                                "name":"fileInMountsInfo.xml"
                            }
                        },
                        "clear_refs":
                        {
                            "file":
                            {
                                "name":"fileInClear_Refs.xml"
                            }
                        }                   
                    }
                }
            },
            "14":
            {
                "file":
                {
                    "name":"fileIn14.xml"
                },
                "task":
                {
                    "file":
                    {
                        "name":"fileInTask.xml"
                    },
                    "loginUid":
                    {
                        "file":
                        {
                            "name":"fileInloginUid.xml"
                        }                   
                    },
                    "sessionid":
                    {
                        "file":
                        {
                            "name":"fileInsessionid.xml"
                        }                   
                    },
                    "coreDump_filter":
                    {
                        "file":
                        {
                            "name":"fileIncoreDump_filter.xml"
                        }                   
                    },
                    "io":
                    {
                        "file":
                        {
                            "name":"fileInIo.xml"
                        }                   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a JSON file that allows consumer component of the JSON to navigate through this directory structure.  I have been trying to use the `Directory`, `File` and `Path` classes but perhaps the best way is to use the java.serializor(?) class to construct the JSON as I loop through the array, parsing its directories and files as i go?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show an example of the JSON output you would want to create, given the string array shown above?

Comment: Sure, see above, that would be a great output.

Comment: Where do the file names come from?  Are they just assumed from the directory names (one file per directory)?

Comment: They are example file names. I put them in as i noted that the example had no files mentioned.. Example updated

Comment: OK, so the file names will be part of the `dirArray`.  Can I assume there will always be exactly one file per directory?  If not, then the JSON will need to change (you would need an array for the files in the JSON at each directory level).  Also, can I assume there will be no directory called "file"?  If any directory can be called "file", then you will need to change the JSON to account for that as well since there can't be two keys with the same name at the same level in the JSON.

Comment: yes the files names are in in dir array, if no files in dir then itl just end with dir name. You can not assume one file per dir - good spot. no dirs called file is a valid assumption if it makes your life easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I would approach this problem by breaking it into two parts.  First, we need a way to parse apart the array of directory/file paths and put it into a hierarchical structure.  Second, we need to take that structure and turn it into JSON.  (I wasn't entirely sure from your question which serializer you wanted to use, so for this answer I will assume that [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) is OK.)

For the first part, I would create a `Dir` class which has a name, a dictionary of child directories (for easy lookup) and a set of files.  We can make a method in this class which will parse apart a path and either find or add the appropriate child objects.

```
class Dir
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dir> Dirs { get; set; }
    public HashSet<string> Files { get; set; }

    public Dir(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Dirs = new Dictionary<string, Dir>();
        Files = new HashSet<string>();
    }

    public Dir FindOrCreate(string path, bool mightBeFile = true)
    {
        int i = path.IndexOf('/');
        if (i > -1)
        {
            Dir dir = FindOrCreate(path.Substring(0, i), false);
            return dir.FindOrCreate(path.Substring(i + 1), true);
        }

        if (path == "") return this;

        // if the name is at the end of a path and contains a "." 
        // we assume it is a file (unless it is "." by itself)
        if (mightBeFile && path != "." && path.Contains("."))
        {
            Files.Add(path);
            return this;
        }

        Dir child;
        if (Dirs.ContainsKey(path))
        {
            child = Dirs[path];
        }
        else
        {
            child = new Dir(path);
            Dirs.Add(path, child);
        }
        return child;
    }
}
```

Using this class, we can easily loop through the `dirArray` given in your question and make the directory hierarchy:

```
Dir root = new Dir("");
foreach (string dir in dirArray)
{
    root.FindOrCreate(dir);
}
```

So at this point, `root` now has the entire directory hierarchy.  If you wanted to, you could simply serialize this object directly with Json.Net to get a reasonable JSON structure.  However, it will be a little more verbose than what you described in your question.  Here is the JSON that would be produced:

```
{
  "Name": "",
  "Dirs": {
    ".": {
      "Name": ".",
      "Dirs": {
        "proc": {
          "Name": "proc",
          "Dirs": {
            "15": {
              "Name": "15",
              "Dirs": {
                "task": {
                  "Name": "task",
                  "Dirs": {
                    "15": {
                      "Name": "15",
                      "Dirs": {
                        "exe": {
                          "Name": "exe",
                          "Dirs": {},
                          "Files": []
                        },
                        "mounts": {
                          "Name": "mounts",
                          "Dirs": {},
                          "Files": [
                            "mounts.xml"
                          ]
                        },
                        "mountinfo": {
                          "Name": "mountinfo",
                          "Dirs": {},
                          "Files": [
                            "mountinfo.xml",
                            "moremountinfo.xml"
                          ]
                        },
                        "clear_refs": {
                          "Name": "clear_refs",
                          "Dirs": {},
                          "Files": [
                            "clear_ref.xml"
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "Files": []
                    }
                  },
                  "Files": []
                }
              },
              "Files": []
            },
            "14": {
              "Name": "14",
              "Dirs": {
                "loginuid": {
                  "Name": "loginuid",
                  "Dirs": {},
                  "Files": [
                    "loginuid.xml"
                  ]
                },
                "sessionid": {
                  "Name": "sessionid",
                  "Dirs": {},
                  "Files": [
                    "sessionid.xml"
                  ]
                },
                "coredump_filter": {
                  "Name": "coredump_filter",
                  "Dirs": {},
                  "Files": [
                    "coredump_filter.xml"
                  ]
                },
                "io": {
                  "Name": "io",
                  "Dirs": {},
                  "Files": [
                    "io.xml"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "Files": []
            }
          },
          "Files": []
        }
      },
      "Files": []
    }
  },
  "Files": []
}
```

To get the JSON you are aiming for, we will need a `JsonConverter` class:

```
class DirConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Dir));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Dir dir = (Dir)value;
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        if (dir.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            JArray files = new JArray();
            foreach (string name in dir.Files)
            {
                files.Add(new JValue(name));
            }
            obj.Add("list_of_files", files);
        }
        foreach (var kvp in dir.Dirs)
        {
            obj.Add(kvp.Key, JToken.FromObject(kvp.Value, serializer));
        }
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

We can serialize the directory hierarchy using the converter like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new DirConverter());
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settings);
```

Here is the output.  Note that I changed the "file" properties in your original JSON to arrays, and renamed it to "list_of_files" to accommodate the possibility of multiple files per directory, per your comments.  I am also assuming that there will never be an actual directory called "list_of_files".  If that is a possibility, you would need to change the name of the files array to something else that will not collide with any of your directory names.  (If you ever encounter an error that says "`Can not add property list_of_files to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object`" that means you have a directory somewhere in your data with the name "list_of_files".)

```
{
  ".": {
    "proc": {
      "15": {
        "task": {
          "15": {
            "exe": {},
            "mounts": {
              "list_of_files": [
                "mounts.xml"
              ]
            },
            "mountinfo": {
              "list_of_files": [
                "mountinfo.xml"
              ]
            },
            "clear_refs": {
              "list_of_files": [
                "clear_ref.xml"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "14": {
        "loginuid": {
          "list_of_files": [
            "loginuid.xml"
          ]
        },
        "sessionid": {
          "list_of_files": [
            "sessionid.xml"
          ]
        },
        "coredump_filter": {
          "list_of_files": [
            "coredump_filter.xml"
          ]
        },
        "io": {
          "list_of_files": [
            "io.xml"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ConJiu

Comment: Wow, this looks brilliant, i will take some time to look over it and integrate it and test. Il get back to you when iv done that :)

Comment: Hey Brian, i get the following error at JSON.Convert.Serialize(root, settings - Can not add property files to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object.) I'm guessing its the json has 2 objects with the same name?

Comment: In fact it has to be the actual data in the array that is issue as yourexample works...

Comment: I cant seem to find the issue, if there is a way to send you my arraylist let me know.

Comment: From the error, I'm guessing that you have a directory called "files" somewhere in your array.  Remember when I asked whether I could assume there would be no such directory and you said I could make that assumption?  To fix, change the code in the converter so that it writes a property name of `_files` (or something else of your choosing) instead.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Tried that already, still same answer. Perhaps the problem is that i have grabbed files and directories, a lot of directories are empty, could that be the issue?

Comment: It shouldn't be; your example array in your question had an empty directory (`./proc/15/task/15/exe`).  Can you edit the fiddle I linked to at the bottom of my answer (fork it if you need to) to demonstrate the problem?  You can put your full array in there.

Comment: will do, altough my aray is 299,000 length so prob not possible

Comment: OK, if that won't work you could try posting your array on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) - according to their FAQ it has a limit of 512KB.

Comment: its >5 mb, i cut it down and it worked so maybe its the version of json.net im using, i chose the 3.5 version, il up it to 4

Comment: I think your original thought is correct: it is something in the data itself.  You could try a binary search approach-- divide your data in half.  Run the code with each half.  Whichever half fails, divide that half in two and repeat.  Do that enough times until you've zeroed in on the file or directory that is causing the issue.

Comment: Understood, im doing it but the data sloooooowws down my comp and still havnt found issue. Il work it and get back to you. Cheers for patiance and help

Comment: Same problem.  You have an actual folder named "_files".  So, I changed the converter again.  Now it will output "list_of_files".  Hopefully you don't have any folders with that name!  Note: I also noticed another problem-- some of your folders have a "." in the name, e.g. "4.3.6".  Previously the code was assuming folders would not have "." in the name.  So now it will only treat something as a file if the name has a "." AND is in the last part of the path.

Comment: Thats it sir. I must say thats the best help i have received on SO. Thanks a million for your help and patience. It is very much appreciated. i added a bounty as a token of my appreciation.

Comment: Is there an easy way to format the output to get each key and object on its own line?

Comment: No.  In Json.Net you can either have indented formatting (which is what is shown in my answer above) or you can have no formatting (all whitespace and line breaks are removed).  The former is more readable by humans; the latter is more compact.  If you want some other formatting you'd need to implement your own JsonTextWriter.  That is way beyond the scope of this answer.  Thanks for adding the bounty!

Comment: ok thx, i see that the formating is undone byu my own code, recified nowe. Thx!

Comment: Thanks @Brian Rogers, you make my day, I was searching something like that and I find your solution and is very awesome!