# How to create an XML document from multiple x-paths using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have multiple paths stored in an array in c#. I want to be able to create an xml document using these x-paths but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Here are some examples of the x-paths..

`/B/Name/FirstName`

`/B/Name/LastName`

`/B/Name/MiddleName`

`/B/Job/Title`

So the xml would look like this

```
<B>
  <Name>
    <FirstName>
    </FirstName>
    <LastName>
    </LastName>
    <MiddleName>
    </MiddleName>
  </Name>
  <Job>
    <Title>
    </Title>
  </Job>
</B>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are those paths in something like this `string[] paths;`?

Comment: that is correct, I have it in a string array

Comment: Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26615480/832052), but xml instead of json.